# MongoDB Generated Value starting with 1

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Java class annotated with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` like this:

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

@Entity
public class Test {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public long id;
...
}
```

The point is that whenever I create a Test instance, it generates a MongoDB document with initial Id as `0`, but I would like it to start with `1` instead (as this will be used as Id in my WebService URL).

Is that possible?

Answer (score -3):

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
public int id=1;
```

Comment: But this makes every new object to have `id=1`, instead of incrementally add it.

Comment: it's taking default value as 0 . first assign the value as 1 then increment it

Comment: But then I would need to control it in application level, but I'd rather delegate this to the MongoDB itself (as it is in my question).

Comment: @Vijay you got downvoted because your answer seems to force-construct every entity of type test to id=1 ... BUT i wonder if this actually is overridden by the Mongo-db Annotation later, resulting in the exact behaviour that was requested? Is this a working hack - or a wrong answer? Did somebody test this?